# Custom Spatial Convolution in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, convolution

I'd like to extend TensorFlow's `tf.nn.conv2d` function by having it threshold the input (with a sigmoid or ReLU function) in each receptive field before multiplying by the filter. The actual convolution operation is implemented in Eigen, and Eigen's convolution functionality is in a function called [choose](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/NeuralNetworks/SpatialConvolutions.h#L768). However, I have not been able to find the implementation for the `choose` function.

Where is the `choose` function located in the TensorFlow github repository, and is there any simple way to extend Eigen's convolution function to do input processing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Eigen supports both row-major and col-major memory layouts. The 'choose' template selects the appropriate convolution code path depending on the layout of the input data. The template itself is implemented in http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/TensorMeta_8h_source.html

The actual convolution is peformed as a matrix multiplication (called a contraction) between the convolution weights (aka the kernels) and the 2d patches extracted from the input image.

Comment: Why is it called a contraction, if I may ask? Is this somehow related to contraction mappings? What I'm interested in knowing is whether they ensure that the convolutions are contraction mappings. Thanks.